# Could not write CursorWindow to Parcel due to error -2147483641

Tags: android, parcelable, runtimeexception

I'm sending/receiving a custom `Query` object between processes. `Query` implements `Parcelable` and wraps a `CursorWindow` instance. First, I send it from process A to process B through a `Messenger`. This works just fine. But when sending this same instance from process B to process C through an `Intent`, it throws this error:

```
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not write CursorWindow to Parcel due to error -2147483641.
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeWriteToParcel(Native Method)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.database.CursorWindow.writeToParcel(CursorWindow.java:701)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at com.blablabla.android.helpers.db.cursor.ParcelableCursor.writeToParcel(ParcelableCursor.java:461)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1254)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1173)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6475)
E/com.blablabla.android.widget.ZKWidgetManager( 4583): at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:1984)
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class ParcelableCursor implements Parcelable, CrossProcessCursor {

    /** Cursor data window */
    protected CursorWindow window = CursorHelper.getCursorWindowInstance(); // This just does a new CursorWindow(false) for 2.x compatibility reasons.

    [...]

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
        out.writeParcelable(this.window, 0); // <<<<< Exception thrown here
        [...]
    }
}
```

Testing `Intent`:

```
ParcelableCursor test = new ParcelableCursor();

final Bundle bndl = new Bundle(); // Or with ClassLoader
bndl.putParcelable(BUNDLE, test);


intent.setAction(RECEIVER_QUERY_NAME);
intent.putExtra(QUERY, bndl);
```

As you can see this is not a data problem since this example `ParcelableCursor` is effectively empty. Also using the new `CursorWindow(String)` constructor instead of deprecated `CursorWindow(boolean)` did not help.

Does anyone what this error code means or where to look this error code up?

Any hints appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: [This issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4470) is probably closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up making a separate implementation of this `ParcelableCursor` to use for `Intent` (`ParcelableCursorForIntent`) that does not use `CursorWindow` internally but only `List` and `Map`.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue and found this quesitons. Would you be kind enough to open source ParcelableCursorForIntent?

Comment: I can't. Anyway it's pretty straight-forward to implement using Lists and Maps.